# keystroke to clear screen in psql?

Tags: psql, postgresql-9.3

I want a shortcut key to clear the screen in my (Windows 7) psql console just like CTRL-l clears the screen in my R console. I am tired of typing '! cls'. Do I need to write a macro for this? I am running Postgres 9.35. '\r' resets the query buffer but does not clear the screen.

Comment: For `psql` on Linux, control-L . It isn't supported under Windows; unsure if there's a different keyboard shortcut or if there just isn't one. `psql` isn't as full featured under Windows because none of the PostgreSQL developers use Windows for day to day work. Patches are welcome ;-)

Comment: We are not living in perfect world. Some of us still using windows for work. Use `\! cls` to clear screen. Generally, use `\! command` to invoke command from current console (cmd.exe).

Comment: I am on Windows 7. I found CTRL + SHIFT + L worked for me. Postgresql 12.

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + L` doesn't seem to work on Windows 10 [Pro]. I tried it on Postgres 12.4 and it didn't work. `\! cls` works great!

Answer (score 229):

As an alternative to Ctrl-L use, e.g. for scripts in an linux environment:

```
\! clear
```

or

```
\! cls
```

for Microsoft.

Answer (score 89):

Please use: **CTRL + L**

Check out the link: http://postgresql.nabble.com/psql-in-bash-how-to-clear-screen-td2141886.html

Comment: I'm on Postgres 11.5 on Windows 10 and this doesn't work. It just adds `^L` on the line

Comment: I had the same issue. I got it working with CTRL + SHIFT + L instead. I am using Windows 7, postgresql 12.

Comment: Works on Mac, too!

Comment: @Kenmore  SEEMS Working on WSL Env.

Answer (score 21):

In case **CTRL + L** doesn't work on the ***Windows OS***, use:

```
\! cls
```

Ensure there is `SPACE` between `\!` and `cls`, hit `ENTER`.

Answer (score 5):

`\! cls` + Enter

can be usedfor Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

This works for me using postgresql in Windows 10 with Bash:

```
\! clear
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read this to learn about Bash:  https://opensource.com/resources/what-bash

Answer (score 0):

When using psql ((PostgreSQL) 14.4) through linux terminal just use:

CTRL + Shift + L

It will clear outputs and move cursor to the top of terminal window.

:)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WSL and a Docker Container, only works with:

```
\clear
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).